# IPv6 issues with Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, ipv6

We have a Windows Server 2012 domain. The server acts as our DHCP and DNS. About 2 weeks ago, Comcast changed something in their router I believe, enabling IPv6. Since IPv6 was never initially set up on our Windows 2012 server, the router was now acting as DHCP for IPv6 addresses. Because of that, none of our pc's in the domain could resolve names since it was no longer using IPv4 and our own DNS server.

I found the setting in the Comcast router to turn off IPv6 DHCP, but it appears the damage is already done. I don't know anything about IPv6 and am the "pseudo" IT guy in the office. I've had to go to all the affected machines and ran "ipconfig /release6" as well as remove all the IPv6 DNS entries on our Windows 2012 Server.

This seemed to "band-aid" the situation, but client machines keep getting IPv6 and DNS keeps getting screwed up.

Can anyone lend some advice on what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using a _residential_ Comcast connection, rather than a _business_ connection?!

Comment: No we are Comcast Business class

Comment: Hm. You should have received a notice that IPv6 was going live, ahead of time, so that you could prepare for it. Anyway, you may as well just sort out the actual problem; you're going to need IPv6 soon enough anyway. Unfortunately you didn't really describe the actual problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sure the problem is that the router has stateless autoconf configured (our new Comcast Business modem did) and the clients are preferring the IPv6 configuration, including mDNS addresses or Comcast DNS server, over their internal IPv4 scheme, including DNS on their server.

Comment: Can you control the route advertisements in your Comcast router?  You probably should enable the 'Managed' flag and setup your IPv6 Scope including the correct DNS options on your DHCP server.

Comment: @Zoredache Comcast only does dynamic prefix allocations, and only by DHCPv6; and Windows doesn't support that, so... yeah.

Comment: @ChrisS Not sure if that's correct - they use DHCP-PD to delegate a prefix, and then internally, they use SLAAC. That's IME anyway...

Comment: I believe EEAA is correct - that's what happens for me, it may depend on where you live.  Comcast's details on their specific rollout methodology are always of the "we did it" type

Comment: @EEAA, I meant that the Windows DHCPv6 Server can't get it's prefix from DHCP-PD. Windows can pickup an address from a DHCPv6 server or SLAAC.

Comment: @ChrisS Ahh, got it. Agreed on that point.

Answer (score 3):

Band-aid: Login to your modem and disable IPv6 Stateless and Stateful (DHCPv6) Auto-configuration. Also check that DHCPv4 isn't enabled, it's enabled by default. This will just leave you without IPv6 support.

As Michael mentioned above, IPv6 isn't required by very many websites yet, but with IPv4 exhaustion really happening right now (like you can't get IPv4 addresses in parts of the world anymore), there will be more and more IPv6-only sites in the near future.

The "real solution" is to setup DHCP on the router instead of the Server. Windows doesn't play very well with IPv6, at least it's DHCPv6 is "lacking". So you'll run into quite a few problems using it as the DHCPv6 server. The problem with setting up the router as the DHCPv6 server is that you'll lose AD Integrated DNS updates. This can be configured around, but isn't easy. So my suggested "real solution" is to call a local consultant who can configure everything for you.

Comment: A few parts of what I manage are already IPv6-only. And simply having IPv6 has its own advantages, like being able to get rid of the jumpboxes, simplifying VPNs, etc.

Comment: I should note: I really hate my own answer here, but the EXTREME lack of IPv6 support in Windows hamstrings what I can honestly suggest people try to setup.

Comment: You will lose integrated DHCP updates but not systems that register themselves in DNS with an AD integrated zone.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisS I think I may have to call someone. I'm over my head here.

Comment: I agree with the IPv6 support, its unfortunately similar to FreeBSD.